# how to make use of google map javascript

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, jakarta-ee

please i need help on how to display the google map on a page. i used the sample code from developers google console and i obtain a key fro them but nothing was showing when i loaded the html file.

the javascript code is as below

```
// Reference to the Firebase database.
var firebase = new Firebase("http://firebaseio.com");

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
    zoom: 3
  });

  // Add marker on user click
  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    firebase.push({lat: e.latLng.lat(), lng: e.latLng.lng()});
  });

  // Create a heatmap.
  var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: [],
    map: map,
    radius: 8
  });

  firebase.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
    // Get latitude and longitude from Firebase.
    var newPosition = snapshot.val();

    // Create a google.maps.LatLng object for the position of the marker.
    // A LatLng object literal (as above) could be used, but the heatmap
    // in the next step requires a google.maps.LatLng object.
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newPosition.lat, newPosition.lng);
    
    heatmap.getData().push(latLng);
  });
}
```

the html code is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>

<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7Zr0DZ906x5OH2ODTJZ-O2CxO00khPnI&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">

    </script>
    <script src="map.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i just saved the html and javascript codes with notepad, am running on local not remote.

Comment: google map doesn't work on local server if you connect  with internet then working properly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to show the google map on your webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

replace the latitude and longitude by the LatLng();

Comment: this answer helped me to display the map, i didn't really understood the second answer. thanks but please, this is a final year project am working on, i need to get some clicks to database, and display some texts and textfields also, is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am putting an example which I had develop for saving the `lng` and `lat` from the map and display the same when user is selected from the view page.

First, create a project with scaffold and then add the following in your _form file and show file make sure you use div id to call the java/script:

```
    <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&sensor=false&client=&key=&libraries=geometry&language=&hl=&region="></script> 
    <script src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
```

And here is the java script which store the `lng` and `lat`:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.18061975930,79.36565089010);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom:7,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            // marker refers to a global variable
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
                // get lat/lon of click
                var clickLat = event.latLng.lat();
                var clickLon = event.latLng.lng();

                // show in input box
                document.getElementById("lat").value = clickLat.toFixed(5);
                document.getElementById("lon").value = clickLon.toFixed(5);

                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(clickLat,clickLon),
                        map: map
                     });
            });
    }   

        window.onload = function () { initialize() };

    </script>
```

Add the following in the show page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("<%= @person.latitude %>","<%= @person.longitude %>");
            var myOptions = {
                zoom:7,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            // marker refers to a global variable
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map
            });
    }   

        window.onload = function () { initialize() };

    </script>
```

Finally on your index page add the following:

```
<script>
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
</script>
```

Comment: please, seems the second answer is on json or something, i can only attempt java, want to display some texts and forms on the map page. Help me on j2ee 1.4. how can i also make the map responsive by tracing location with marker

Comment: you can use the following link which has some example of making map responsive https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/responsive-google-maps/

Comment: Also in the above answer sorry that I am not able to give you clear view. This example is doing work like when you click on the map it will display the lng and lat in the text filed and then store in the database. java/script work in any language , database is postgres